# What is the proper way to create a dump file when an ASP.NET application gets the yellow screen of death for a page?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, windbg, visual-studio-debugging

I want to get the dump file so that I can step through the code and see what the state of the application was (the values of variables, etc) at the time of the yellow screen of death error page. This is to investigate an intermittent issue.

What's the proper way to create this dump file? Or, is there a better way to investigate this kind of intermittent issue?

To be clear, the whole application does not crash. It's just one page that intermittently gets an exception thrown.

Answer (score 3):

In `Application_Error` you can write a dump file. The following code creates a dump similar to WinDbg's `.dump /ma` command. I use this in WinForms applications. Just make sure you have access to the folder where you want to write the dump. I'm not sure if code running in ASP.NET has enough permissions to access all that process information.

```
[Flags]
enum MiniDumpOptions
{
    MiniDumpNormal = 0x00000000,
    MiniDumpWithDataSegs = 0x00000001,
    MiniDumpWithFullMemory = 0x00000002,
    MiniDumpWithHandleData = 0x00000004,
    MiniDumpFilterMemory = 0x00000008,
    MiniDumpScanMemory = 0x00000010,
    MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules = 0x00000020,
    MiniDumpWithIndirectlyReferencedMemory = 0x00000040,
    MiniDumpFilterModulePaths = 0x00000080,
    MiniDumpWithProcessThreadData = 0x00000100,
    MiniDumpWithPrivateReadWriteMemory = 0x00000200,
    MiniDumpWithoutOptionalData = 0x00000400,
    MiniDumpWithFullMemoryInfo = 0x00000800,
    MiniDumpWithThreadInfo = 0x00001000,
    MiniDumpWithCodeSegs = 0x00002000,
    MiniDumpWithoutAuxiliaryState = 0x00004000,
    MiniDumpWithFullAuxiliaryState = 0x00008000,
    MiniDumpWithPrivateWriteCopyMemory = 0x00010000,
    MiniDumpIgnoreInaccessibleMemory = 0x00020000,
    MiniDumpWithTokenInformation = 0x00040000,
    MiniDumpWithModuleHeaders = 0x00080000,
    MiniDumpFilterTriage = 0x00100000,
}

const MiniDumpOptions WinDbgFullDumpOptions = 
    MiniDumpOptions.MiniDumpWithFullMemory |
    MiniDumpOptions.MiniDumpWithHandleData |
    MiniDumpOptions.MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules |
    MiniDumpOptions.MiniDumpWithFullMemoryInfo |
    MiniDumpOptions.MiniDumpWithThreadInfo |
    MiniDumpOptions.MiniDumpWithTokenInformation;

[DllImport("dbghelp.dll")]
static extern bool MiniDumpWriteDump(IntPtr hProcess, int processId,
    IntPtr hFile, MiniDumpOptions dumpType, IntPtr exceptionParam,
    IntPtr userStreamParam, IntPtr callackParam);

public static void WriteFullMemoryDump(string dumpFileName)
{
    using (var stream = File.Open(dumpFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        if (stream.SafeFileHandle != null)
            MiniDumpWriteDump(process.Handle, process.Id, stream.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), WinDbgFullDumpOptions, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle `Application_Error` in your `Global.asax` code-behind class.

In the method, call the `this.Server.GetLastError()` to retrieve the last-thrown exception, also call `this.Request.SaveAs( fileName )` to save the HTTP request (request headers and request body) that accessed the page.

The CLR does not provide any (easy) means for applications to "dump", however, so you cannot do post-mortem debugging, however the information contained within the Exception's `StackTrace` property and the saved request should be enough to successfully investigate the problem or reproduce the problem locally.